# Unicity of the characters of a string in c

Tags: c, string, loops, char, substring

Is there any efficient simple and easy way to check the unicity of the characters of a string in c?
In my case I have to check if the ISBN entered by the user has unique characters and has a length of 13 characters.

Comment: ISBNs are made of digits. There are 10 digits (0 to 9). It is not possible for each digit in a 13-digit numeral to be unique within the numeral, as there must be repetitions after ten different digits are used. Edit the problem to clarify what you mean. Show examples of right and wrong inputs.

Comment: In this case I am using a  13 characters ISBN (imaginary one since it is just a project)for ex: 1234567890qwe or asdfghjklyxcv.
wrong input : 12345617890qw

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient, simple, and easy".  The straightforward approach seems to meet those criteria. (Scan the string, record seen entries in an array, invalidate if you see a dup or count over 13)

Comment: As short as possible as it is a long and complicated project and I am a beginner

Answer (score 1):

Given the string is supposed to have only 13 bytes, a brute force method seems fast enough if not faster than more elaborate ones and much easier to write and proof check.

Here is an example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check_ISBN(const char *p) {
    if (strlen(p) != 13)
        return -1;
    while (*p) {
        unsigned char c = *p++;
        // characters must be digits or lowercase letters
        if (!isdigit(c) && !islower(c))
            return 2;
        // characters must not be duplicated
        if (strchr(p, c))
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int status = 0;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s ISBN ...\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        switch (check_ISBN(argv[i])) {
          case 0:
            printf("%s: valid ISBN.\n", argv[i]);
            break;
          case 1:
            printf("%s: invalid ISBN: duplicate digit.\n", argv[i]);
            status = 1;
            break;
          case 2:
            printf("%s: invalid ISBN: invalid character.\n", argv[i]);
            status = 1;
            break;
          default:
            printf("%s: invalid ISBN: bad character count.\n", argv[i]);
            status = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Nice one. Just one point, OP does not seem to explicitly exclude the upper cases.

Comment: @Zilog80: yes the OP does not, but his examples only show lowercase letters. If uppercase is also allowed, another question pops up: is the unicity test case sensitive? I chose to keep the implementation simple and only allow digits and lowercase letters and made this explicit in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the string, recording each seen character in a look up table.  If you see a dup, abort.  If the length isn't 13 fail. eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <limits.h>

int
validate(const char *a, char **err)
{
        char lut[(1 << CHAR_BIT)] = {0};  /* 256 */
        int len = 0;
        *err = "too short";
        for(const char *s = a; *s; s += 1 ){
                if( ++len > 13 ){
                        *err = "too long";
                        return 0;
                }
                if( lut[(unsigned char)*s] ){
                        *err = "duplicate entry";
                        return 0;
                }
                lut[(unsigned char)*s] = 1;
        }
        return len == 13;
}


int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int fail = 0;
        if( argc == 1 ){
                printf("usage: %s isbn [isbn...]\n", basename(argv[0]));
                return 0;
        }

        for( argv += 1; *argv; argv += 1 ){
                char *e;
                if( ! validate(*argv, &e) ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "%s is invalid: %s\n", *argv, e);
                        fail += 1;
                }
                else {
                        printf("%s is valid\n", *argv);
                }
        }
        return fail == 0 ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Comment: The `lut` array needs to be one element longer (or one needs to be subtracted when indexing it), since `(1 << CHAR_BIT) - 1` is a valid character value,  and the character values need to be unsigned, which `char` does not guarantee. Casting to `int` is pointless.

Comment: C as it is *meant* to be written - dense, terse, with a slight contempt for anyone reading it.  I approve!

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ack.  Yes, of course the lut needs to be 256 long.  Thanks for pointing that out.  A self-inflicted off by one error.  The cast is just to suppress a compiler warning.

Comment: @JohnBode I suppressed the desire to write `if( lut[*s]++ )` for the sake of readability. :)

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out

Comment: @EricPostpischil Argh.  Thanks you for pointing out the pointlessness of the cast.  It continues to amaze me how easy it is to make silly mistakes like this in C.  I've not used it much for several years, and have recently taken to answering questions on SO to refresh myself.  Subtle mistakes are everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

To add to @WilliamPursell answer, here's a way using a bit mask instead of char array lookup table :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
// Check if this is a ISBN and its 13 digits uniqueness.
// Parameters:
//    ISBN, ASCIIZ
// Returns: [int]
//     -1 :  Not a ISBN
//      0 :  ISBN with only unique digits
//      1 :  ISBN with duplicated digits
int isISBNDigitsUnique(char *pStr) {
    if (pStr == NULL) return -1;
    unsigned long long mask = 0, refmask; 
    unsigned char bit;
    int expected_length = 0, ret = 0;    
    while((bit = *pStr++) && expected_length++ < 14) {
      if (bit < '0' || bit > '9' && bit < 'A') return -1;
      if ((bit &= 0xDFu) > 'Z') return -1;
      if (ret==0) {
        refmask = mask; 
        if ((bit -= 0x10u) > 0x30u) bit -= 0x20u; 
        if ((mask |= (0x01u << bit)) == refmask) ret = 1;
      }
    }
    if (expected_length != 13) return -1;
    return ret;
}
int main(int nbargs, char *args[]) {
    if (nbargs != 2) {
       printf("Usage : %s ISBN\n", args[0]);
       return 1;
    }
    switch (isISBNDigitsUnique(args[1])) {
      case 1:
        printf("duplicate digit!\n");
        break;
      case 0:
        printf("all digits are unique.\n");
        break;
      default:
        printf("%s is not an ISBN.\n", args[1]);
   }
}
```

The boolean logic applied to each digit :

We consider that 0-9, a-z and A-Z are the only valid digits for an ISBN.
As we have an ASCIIZ buffer for the ISBN, we can expect for each digit the
following binary values for the digit ASCII code.

```
0011 0000 to 0011 1001 => digits 0-9
0100 0001 to 0101 1010 => digits A-Z
0110 0001 to 0111 1010 => digits a-z
```

We first check that the digit meets the following requirements :

- If the digit code is lower than 48 then it's not a valid digit.
- If the digit code is greater than 57 and lower than 65 then it's not a valid
  digit.

We apply case reduction by zeroing the 7th bit, so an AND mask with 0xDF.
We have then the following range of values for the digit :

```
0001 0000 to 0001 1001 => digits 0-9
0100 0001 to 0101 1010 => digits A-Z
0100 0001 to 0101 1010 => digits a-z
```

If the digit code is greater than 90 then it's not a valid digit.

We substract 0x10 to the digit code, the goal is to fit a 64 bits mask for each values.
We have then the following range of values for the digit :

```
0000 0000 to  0000 1001 => digits 0-9, decimal values 0-9
0011 0001 to  0100 1010 => digits A-Z, decimal values 49-74
0011 0001 to  0100 1010 => digits a-z, decimal values 49-74
```

We can zeroing the 6th bit as the 5th bit is enough to distinct 0-9 from A-Z, but as our resulting range would exceed 64 it's more efficient to substract 0x20 if the digit code is greater than 48.
We have then the following range of values for the digit :

```
0000 0000 to 0000 1001 0-9 => digits 0-9, decimal values 0-9
0001 0001 to 0010 1010 A-Z => digits A-Z, decimal values 17-42
0001 0001 to 0010 1010 a-z => digits a-z, decimal values 17-42
```

Our range of values for the digit code is now 0-9 and 17-42, which fit easily a 64 bits masks. So we just have to flag each bit for each digit and if a digit code does not change the mask then we have a duplicate digit.

P.S.: @interjay For a math approach, i look to check digits sum **and** digits product, but that need a math demonstration....

Comment: Do not use `0x39` for the character “9”. Use `'9'`. There is no reason to use numeric codes for characters except when writing software that needs to use non-native character codes (such as software that translates between EBCDIC and ASCII).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Done. As its ASCII code checks, i wasn't sure if mixing char comparaisons and mask hex values was readable. I'll follow your pov.